# Ito process on small intervals

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Consider an Ito process
$$
X(t) = \int_0^t \tilde B(s)\, dB(s), \quad t\in[0,T],
$$
where $B(s),\tilde B(s)$ are independent Brownian motions.

Let $\pi^l=\{0=t_0^l<t_1^l<\dots < t^l_{m(l)}=T\}$ be a sequence of partitions of $[0,T]$ s.t. $\max\limits_{i}(t^l_{i+1}-t^l_i)\to 0$ as $l\to\infty$. I want to prove that
$$
\sup\limits_{l}\sum_{i=0}^{m(l)-1}\big|X(t^l_{i+1}) -X(t^l_{i}) - \tilde B(t^l_i)\big(B(t^l_{i+1}) - B(t^l_{i})\big) \big| < \infty \quad \text{a.s.}
$$
First I thought about estimating
$|\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}\tilde B(s) - \tilde B(t_i)\, dB(s)|$, but haven not found useful majorants.

Comment: What properties do you assume for $f$ ?

Comment: @TheBridge For example $f(s)$ could be another Brownian motion.

Comment: Well then you should reconsider you notation, $f(s)$ is usually used for deterministic functions (or processes), and establish the conditions under which the integral makes sense in the first place. Regards

Comment: I htink you also need to make assumptions over behavior of the mesh of the sequence of partition. Typically it should tend to 0.

Comment: @TheBridge you are right, I have added such an assumption.

Comment: If your BM $\tilde B$ is independent your problem can be reformulated with $\tilde B$ replaced by a continuous function as you can fix the trajectory of $\tilde B$, without touching paths the random process $B$.

Comment: Moreover if your inequality was true in full generality I think that this implies that stochastic integral could be defined almost surely which is false in general (only uniformly in probability over compacts). Though there are theories that allows (some version of ) stochastic integral to be defined almost surely maybe your case falls into this (this paper might be overkill but I couldn't find some gentler references) : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.2981.pdf (of course you have to give something up to get this kind of "gain of function").